# What element is responsible for centering the menu items vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I went to the twitter bootstrap homepage and copy pasted their menu below:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container / I tried 'margin: 0 auto;' since nav is a display block item but with no luck 
      %button.btn.btn-navbar{"data-target" => ".nav-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :type => "button"}
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
      %a.brand{:href => "./index.html"} Bootstrap
      .nav-collapse.collapse
        %ul.nav
          %li.active
            %a{:href => "./index.html"} Home
          %li
            %a{:href => "./getting-started.html"} Get started
          %li
            %a{:href => "./scaffolding.html"} Scaffolding
          %li
            %a{:href => "./base-css.html"} Base CSS
          %li
            %a{:href => "./components.html"} Components
          %li
            %a{:href => "./javascript.html"} JavaScript
          %li
            %a{:href => "./customize.html"} Customize
```

BUT! I my items don't get centered the way theirs are, I tried playing with the safari developers tool but without any luck!

Which element is responsible for centering the items vertically?

[image]

Edit: Here

[image]

Edit: This what I see in Safari Tools for the .container element:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can have a looks at `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` like in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kv3aG/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right then it is the anchor that has a padding: 10px 15px 10px; That*s what centers it vertical and horizontaly.

Comment: Hi I added another screenshot

Comment: Why do u look at the container-class when u wonder about the anchor-tag?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a centering issue. The menu items should be the same height as the navbar itself.
You probably have an element on your navbar that is too tall.